# Is it possible to have a user account management system with MFA on top of a Git repo hosting service?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Github MFA gives an access code to a user for local remote hosting access. Is it possible to have a user account management system with MFA on top of a Git repo hosting service such as Github, Gitlab, and Gitea so that a user can have Git remote operations in the same fashion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. GitHub and GitLab (and I assume Gitea) all offer MFA as a feature and still allow for you to use non-password authentication methods for git operations (ssh keys, access tokens, etc) is that what you are asking?

Comment: I knew that I asked a rare question. We have a Git repo hosting service. Due to a company's requirement, the service needs to use a centralized user account management system, Azure Active Directory, with MFA. To my test, a user can access to the website of the service, but can't do any Git remote operation such as "git clone" in the setup.

Comment: Users won't be able to use HTTPS with a username/password to `git clone` in this setup, however they should still be able to use SSH keys, Personal access tokens, and other mechanisms to clone repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your info. That would bring more complexity to the process. For this reason, the project is on pause. It likely is killed.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should probably describe key details of _what_ you are doing and _why_ you want to do this, key constraints, etc.

Comment: It is a long story. My original design was pressed into a mishap of architecture due to a company requirement. I won't get in any further.